# Unfortunately, Package Installer has stopped while requesting permission in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to request permission to seek permission to read storage. After recent Android Studio upgrade, I started getting error "Unfortunately, Package Installer has stopped" while requesting permission and the permission request dialog does not come up.

Here is the code snippet where I am requesting the permission

```
    int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_READWRITE_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have those permissions listed in the manifest, as well?

Comment: No, but I tried adding them. Does not make any difference.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. I forgot to add same permissions in manifest. I added these permissions in manifest as well, as mike said. Then clean and build and it worked like a charm.

Conclusion: If you are giving the permissions programmatically in class then make sure the same permissions you must declare in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 5):

I had tried this on 2 phones but no luck.

This time, I added the permissions back to manifest file, did clean project and ran again. It worked this time.

Comment: I was adding runtime permissions without mentioning in Manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

I also got the same error "Unfortunately, Package Installer has stopped while requesting permission in Marshmallow".

To resolve this issue, firstly you have to check the size of your app icon or other icons and images used in your application in res(resource) directory. If any one of them icon or image size is too large in that case, we have to face this issue.

Always try to follow Android guidelines of using icons and images in Android Application. So you have to never waste your time on this kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with Marshmallow, but running 'Build -> Clean Project' and then 'Build -> Rebuild Project' did not work.  Then I tried 'File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...' and that did get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case, I clicked on `Deny` on the permission request dialog more than thrice, now the permission request dialog itself not shown and it thrown `Package installer stopped`.

I went to app info screen -> Permissions -> enabled the permission manually, this worked for me.

Also, clearing the app data worked.